# How to insert this sigma equation in R using a For loop?

Tags: r

Equation to calculate the coefficient between two samples with 128 observation each:

[image]

I need to calculate the coefficient between two pixels for 128 observations using the equation. My idea is to use a for loop in R.

The equation is:

Rsi,Sj = sigma N(si sj) - sigma N(si) sigma N(sj) / sqrt [ (sigma N (si^2 - (sigma N si)^2] [N sigma sj^2 - (sigma sj) ^2]

```
My dataset: 2 pixels x 128 observations (spectral bands) which i have in two lists
si = value of the reference pixel
sj = value of the target pixel
N = number of bands (128)
```

I'm very new to coding thus not sure how to tackle this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried to add the equation image but the site doesn't allow me yet to add it.

I don't really know how to put in sigma notations in R so i'm a bit stuck there.